# Defining a variable in terms of another variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

This is a very elementary question, I hope it is still OK to ask it here.

I'd like to do the following

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \def \x {2}
    \def \y {\x + 2}

    \foreach \s in {\x,...,\y}
    {
    % Do things
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives me the error

```
    ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
    <to be read again>
                       +
    1.12 }
```

Why is this not possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TeX doesn't parse math as you want it to do. Here, `\foreach` might be flexible enough to understand it but in general it is a bad idea.

You can force it via PGF math such as

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{int(\x + 2)} %without int \y would be 4.0 instead of 4

\foreach \s in {\x,...,\y}
{
% Do things
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is an expansion issue.  When you use `\def\y{...}` `\y` takes the value that `{....}` has at the time of use, not at the time the definition was made.

Assuming that you're working with integer values, what you want is probably something like

```
\edef\y{\number\numexpr\x+2\relax}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `tikz` way of assigning a value to a macro (`\y`, here) using that of another macro (`\x`, here) is to use

- `\pgfmathsetmacro` (`\y`'s value is then a fixed-point number), or
- `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` (for an integer value).

Here is an example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\x{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xii{\x+0.25*\x}
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{\x+4.5}      

\foreach \s in {\x,\xii,...,\y}{\s,\ }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recommended solution with `fp`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPset\x{2}
\FPeval\y{x+2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \s in {\x,...,\y}
{
    % Do things
    \draw (\s,\s) node {\s};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]